# Hide custom list definition?

Tags: visual-studio, list-definition, hidden

I have a custom list definition, created in visual studio.  We no longer want users to create lists from it.  We have existing lists created from it, therefore deactivating the solution is not an option.  Is there a way to hide the list definition so users can no longer create lists with it?

Comment: Could you please paste the CAML for your list defintions that you created in VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per my understanding, you can do it by Editing **Elements.xml** like **Hidden="True"**

and then deploy once again.

Also, you can do directly by editing

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ *YourSolutionName* \Elements.xml

Jinesh